# numpy.dot for dimensions > 2

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand how dot product works for dimensions more than 2.

The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) says:

> If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last # axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:
>
> ```
> dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
> ```

I don't understand this rule -- where does it come from? Why is it the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b?

Comment: That's just how the function is defined. Someone probably had a reason in mind when they wrote it, but it turned out not to be particularly useful. Later, when they defined the `@` operator, they gave it completely different behavior for dimensions > 2 instead of basing the behavior on `dot`.

Comment: I do not understand, is there an actual mathematical rule for it? Why is it that way.

Comment: @PyWalker2797. It helps to see more dimensions at play. If you make two arrays of say 4D each, you will see immediately why it comes out as it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to visualize this using the notation of `np.einsum`. Start with regular 2D matrix multiplication, which is pretty unambiguous, and follows "normal math" rules:

```
a = np.ones((2, 3))
b = np.ones((3, 4))
np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', a, b)  # Same as a.dot(b)
```

Now prepend a few dimensions:

```
a = np.ones((2, 3, 4, 5))
b = np.ones((8, 7, 5, 6))
np.einsum('ijkl,nolp->ijknop', a, b)  # Same as a.dot(b)
```

In general, a multidimensional array can be thought of as a stack of matrices. There are a number of reasons that numpy generally places the "elements" of an array, whether features, samples, vectors, or matrices along the last dimensions. So, regardless of `dot`, it is fairly standard to think of `a` as a 2x3 array of 4x5 matrices. Similarly, `b` is a 8x7 array of 5x6 matrices.

There are two options going forward. The last two dimensions of the result are unambiguous no matter what choice you make: the output will contain 4x6 matrices. You can compute all the possible combinations of 2x3x8x7 such matrices, or you can expect the leading dimensions to broadcast together. `np.dot` takes the former approach, while `@`/`np.matmul` takes the latter. Anecdotally, I've found that most people will find the latter more intitive.

The exact reason that `np.dot` computes the matrix product of all possible combinations of `a` and `b` is known only to the developers making that choice. It likely revolves around not wanting to raise an error, and the rules of broadcasting not being as universally cemented at the time `dot` was first implemented. Once you decide to take the products of all the combinations, you can decide to do it like this:

```
np.einsum('ijkl,nolp->ijnokp', a, b)  # Not `np.dot`
```

On the one hand, this would reflect the idea of a 2x3x8x7 array of 4x6 matrices better. On the other hand, it creates an awkward permutation of dimensions with `k` out of place in the sequence. The developers went with the arguably less awkward approach of grouping the dimensions from each array separately.

You can always a transpose an array to the shape you want after all.

Answer (score 1):

Standard matrix multiplication definition:

[image: (AB)_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik} B_{kj}]

Which is equivalent to:

```
dot(a, b)[i,j] = sum(a[i,:] * b[:,j])
```

When including more dimensions, we still sum over the last axis of `a` and second-last axis of `b`.

```
dot(a, b)[a1,a2,..., b1,b2,..., i,j] = sum(
    a[a1,a2,...,i,:] *
    b[b1,b2,...,:,j]
)
```

In some sense, the additional dimensions for `a` and `b` can each be imagined as a "multi-dimensional array" of many matrices. And `dot` performs as many standard matrix multiplications as it can with the two "multi-dimensional arrays" of many matrices.

Comment: Not quite. I thought it would do that at first, but it doesn't actually create a stack of matrices quite like you'd expect

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best attempt at making sense of the rule.

Suppose that `a` is a p<sub>1</sub> x ... x p<sub>m-1</sub> x p<sub>m</sub> array and that `b` is a q<sub>1</sub> x ... x q<sub>n-1</sub> x q<sub>n</sub> array. The `dot` function seems to be interpreting `a` as an p<sub>1</sub> x ... x p<sub>m-2</sub> array of p<sub>m-1</sub> x p<sub>m</sub> matrices, and `b` as a q<sub>1</sub> x ... x q<sub>n-2</sub> array of q<sub>n-1</sub> x q<sub>n</sub> matrices.

With that established, the entry `dot(a,b)[i_1,...,i_(n-2),k_1,j_1,...,j_(m-2),k_2]` is the `k_1,k_2` entry of the matrix product
`dot(a[i_1,...,i_(n-2),:,:],b[j_1,...,j_(m-2),:,:])` of a p<sub>m-1</sub> x p<sub>m</sub> with a q<sub>n-1</sub> x q<sub>n</sub>. Notably, this product is only defined if p<sub>m</sub>=q<sub>n-1</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

First try to understand the case where both arrays are 2d.

```
"the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b"
```

How where you taught to do the matrix product by-hand?  I remember tracing my finger across the columns of one array (the last dimension) and down the the rows of the other (first, or 2nd to the last for 2d).

I like the equivalent `einsum` notation, `np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',a,b)`.  Note where the `j` is.

Most articles about matrix multiplication will illustrate this `across/down` calculation, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Illustration

Once we understand the handling of the last 2 dimension, we can address the initial ones. Note that linear-algebra does not define matrix product for "3d" arrays. MATLAB doesn't either.  But `numpy` has extended it to handle the larger number of dimensions.

`np.dot` has been defined to effectively do an 'outer' product on the non-shared dimensions.

```
dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
np.einsum('ijo,kom->ijkm', a, b)
```

`o` is the sum-of-products dimension, last of `a`, 2nd to the last of `b`.  The other dimensions are joined in order, `ij` from `a`, `km` from `b`.  Reducing that to 2d

```
np.einsum('jo,om->jm', a, b)
```

That hasn't been too useful, so more recent versions implement `np.matmul/@` which treats the leading dimensions (before the last 2) as `batch` dimensions, with the added rule that they obey numpy's `broadcasting` rules.

```
a@b   # for 3d arrays, with common leading dimension
np.einsum('ijo,iom->ikm', a, b)     # i is repeated
```

Both `np.dot` and `matmul` have special cases to handle 1d arrays - they are important, but I won't go into those now.